# Creating objects and calling their methods based on keywords in Ada

Tags: pointers, ada

This is a followup to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946382/implementing-an-abstract-function-with-access-types-in-ada).

I got to a point in the program where I felt like I couldn't proceed any further with the current structure, so I did a lot of rewriting. The `Statement` type is no longer abstract, and each subtype of `Statement` creates its own instance of `Statement`'s variables. I also removed the abstract `execute` function from the Statements package because the compiler didn't like that (each subtype will still have its own `execute` method regardless). The `execute` function has been changed to a procedure because the incoming Statement type must be modified. I moved `statementFactory` (formerly createStatement) to the `Statement` package.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
statements-compoundstatements.adb:15:29: expected type "CompoundStatement" defined at statements-compoundstatements.ads:11
statements-compoundstatements.adb:15:29: found type "Statement'Class" defined at statements.ads:6
```

I'm a beginner at Ada, but my hunch is that because the `execute` procedure is in `CompoundStatements` (which is a "subclass" of Statements) it would never be able to see the `execute` method of another "subclass" of Statements. The only solution I can think of would be to dump all the `execute` procedures that call an `execute` procedure into the `Statement` package, but that seems undesirable. But that still doesn't explain why `stmt.all` is being used as a type `Statement'Class` instead of the type created in `statementFactory`.

Here is the new code:

```
package Statements is

   type Statement is tagged private;

   type Statement_Access is access all Statement'Class;
   ParserException : Exception;

   procedure createStatement(tokens : Vector; S : out Statement);
   procedure statementFactory(S: in out Statement; stmt: out Statement_Access);

--.....A bunch of other procedures and functions.....

private
   type Statement is tagged
      record
         tokens : Vector;
         executedtokens : Vector;
      end record;

end Statements;
```

---

```
   procedure createStatement(tokens : Vector; S : out Statement) is
   begin
      S.tokens := tokens;
   end createStatement;

   procedure statementFactory(S: in out Statement; stmt: out Statement_Access) is
      currenttoken : Unbounded_String;
      C            : CompoundStatement;
      A            : AssignmentStatement;
      P            : PrintStatement;

   begin
      currenttoken := getCurrentToken(S);
      if currenttoken = "begin" then
         createStatement(S.tokens, C);
         stmt := new CompoundStatement;
         stmt.all := Statement'Class(C);
      elsif isVariable(To_String(currenttoken)) then
         createStatement(S.tokens, A);
         stmt := new AssignmentStatement;
         stmt.all := Statement'Class(A);
      elsif currenttoken = "print" then
         createStatement(S.tokens, P);
         stmt := new PrintStatement;
         stmt.all := Statement'Class(P);
   end statementFactory;
```

---

```
package body Statements.CompoundStatements is

   procedure execute(skip: in Boolean; C: in out CompoundStatement; reset: out Integer) is
      stmt: Statement_Access;
      tokensexecuted: Integer;
      currenttoken : Unbounded_String;
   begin
      match(C, "begin");
      currenttoken := getCurrentToken(C);
      while(currenttoken /= "end") loop
         statementFactory(C, stmt);
         execute(skip, stmt.all, tokensexecuted); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say “I also removed the abstract execute function from the Statements package because the compiler didn't like that”; but you really need it, because otherwise how is the compiler to know that when you call `execute (skip, stmt.all, tokensexecuted)` that any `stmt.all` will provide an `execute` for it to dispatch to?

Not only does the extended type inherit the attributes of its parent type (so each `CompoundStatement` etc already has `tokens` and `executedtokens`), it inherits the primitive operations of the parent; if the parent operation is `abstract`, the child must provide its own implementation, if not, the child can provide its own (overriding) implementation.

See the [Ada 95 Rationale](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p1-2.html#1) and [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Object_Orientation) for good discussions on this.

Comment: Okay, I added back in `procedure execute(skip: in Boolean; S: in out Statement; reset: out Integer) is abstract;` but the compiler was still complaining that `Statement` wasn't abstract, but I had made that abstract earlier and the compiler didn't like that either. Turns out that I had neglected to also make the record of `Statement` abstract too. That seemed to solve the problem. Spend hours on a problem and it turns out to be something incredibly simple. Thank you again.

Comment: I've spent weeks on this project and it's due Monday but even if I don't get it completely working I feel like I've already learned a ton about Ada and coding that I didn't know before. Also I hate Ada just a little less now that my understanding of it is so much better.  :)